# Difference between Associate Objects vs Properties vs Instance Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I have been digging into some Objective C runtime methods and was wondering what is the difference between Associate Objects and Properties.

I am most interested in their underlying implementation and pros/cons of dynamically using either and if one calls the other or if they are related to each other in any way.

These are the three runtime methods for adding each:

```
class_addProperty (Class cls, const char *name, const objc_property_attribute_t *attributes, unsigned int attributeCount)
```

vs

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy).
```

vs

```
class_addIvar(Class cls, const char *name, size_t size, uint8_t alignment, const char *types)
```

Comment: The two are entirely unrelated concepts. A property is *just* a pair of methods that have a semantic reasoning in the code, it's not required to have any backing memory/storage at all, whereas an associated object is a concrete memory storage point, implemented via a hash table.

Comment: Would it make more sense to ask the difference between Instance Variable and Associate Object? 

An instance variable may be added using :

class_addIvar(Class cls, const char *name, size_t size, uint8_t alignment, const char *types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate answer that comes to mind is that they are totally different, but I can see why someone may get mixed up.

#### Properties

In OOP, in general, a *property* is a *method* of  an *instance* that provides the *interface* to read and/or write a particular data member.

In Objective-C, the `@syntheisze` directive is used to direct the compiler to create or specify the methods to get and/or set some data member of a class instance. The methods themselves are often called "getters" and "setters."

The important thing to keep in mind is that properties are glorified methods.

Real variables, on the other hand, are physically given space (memory) to store their data. Let's say we have a class `NSPerson:`

```
@interface NSPerson : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString *chosenName;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString  *givenName;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString  *fullName;

@end

@implementation NSPerson

@synthesize chosenName = _chosenName, givenName = _givenName

- (NSString *)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.chosenName, self.givenName];
}

@end
```

In this case, the `@synthesize` directive does the following:

- Creates a variable named `_chosenName`
- Creates a method `- (NSString *)chosenName` that returns `_chosenName`
- Creates a method `- (void)setChosenName:(NSString *)chosenName` that sets `_chosenName` to the input
- Does the same three things as above for `givenName`
- Does nothing for `fullName`

Now, `fullName` doesn't need its own memory because it has nothing to store. It also doesn't need a setter for the same reason. Because it is read only and we have explicitly provided an *implementation* of `fullName`, we're done - and `fullName` is a perfectly good property because it's a method that 1) takes no parameters in, and 2) spits the expected type out.

#### Associated Objects

Whereas properties are part of virtually every major OOP language, associated objects in the form that Apple provides are fairly unique to Objective-C.

A better question would have been: what is the difference between a *field* (or *instance variable*) and an *associated object*?

Both fields and associated objects hold data - unlike methods/properties, which just `return` data - and both can be tied to a particular instance.

The way I think of associated objects is by way of analogy. You've probably dealt with some JSON before. A JSON object looks like this:

```
var data = {
    balance: 15.04,
    mood: 'hungry',
    friends: [
         'larry',
         'momed',
         'zeus',
    ]
}
```

Now, each of the keys: `balance` for instance, is paired with a value. In this analogy, keys are the instance variables.

Where might be the associated objects?

```
var associated = {};
var assc = associated[data] = {};  // the INSTANCE data is the KEY of the ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
assc.extrra = "peekaboo";
```

I realize this is not a perfect analogy but I hope it is getting the point across that `associated` above is like the implementation of the Objective-C runtime that allows for associated objects - and that associated objects are variables not methods.

#### Edit: Why associated objects?

I ran out of gas but I wanted to mention that a major use of associated objects is to *back* properties in *categories* and *extensions* that cannot use traditional fields to store data. This is the usual connection between the two with respect to Objective-C.

Comment: Thats a great answer. I have noted that the better question should have been/included instance variable. I will update the question to include instance variable for the benefit of anybody reading this. Great answer.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos will you add Ivar description for the completeness of the answer ?